# How to download a file/Data after verifying the "Content_Type" from **decidePolicyForNavigationResponse** in WKWebview:

Tags: objective-c, download, wkwebview

How to retrieve the actual file/Data after doing some check inside this **decidePolicyForNavigationResponse** delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler
    {

            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;

    }
```

Any leads are welcomed...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but if you want to download a file on a WKWebview, you need to use AFNetworking, the code looks like this :

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = WebView.URL;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: There's no need to use AFNetworking, Foundation's `URLSession` would work just fine.